# Group by a col and concatenate two non group by col in oracel

Tags: oracle, aggregate, rdbms

I'm getting into SQL for the first time after 9 years of work only into Linux. Just during the course of practising sql i was trying to concatenate first_name and last name and get the avg salary of the employees in my table.

table1: Input

```
eid|fname|lname|sal|loc
1  | jake|lee|200|NY
7  | herb|san|500| CA
1  | jake|lee|104| NJ
344| jo|smith|345|TX
```

output:

```
fullname| avg
 jake lee| sal avg value here
 herb san | sal avg value here
 jo smith | sal avg here
```

I tried to use a sub query and then group it based on salary, but it backfired.
Can someone help me understand why it failed

```
select (select fname||lname from empl ) as fullname, avg(salary) from empl GROUP by salary;
```

I even tried grouping by the fullname thinking if that would work.

Comment: `SELECT fname || ' ' || lname "fullname", avg(salary) FROM empl GROUP BY salary;` might work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select fname||'' ||lname, avg(salary)
From t
Group by fname||'' ||lname
```

Group by fname, lname should also work

Comment: thank you :-)... was wondering how would GROUP BY act upon two cols at the same time. Do you know the criteria used for sorting?

Comment: You can use the same technice(s) for order by. Many DBMS also support `order by 1` as a shortcut for ordering by first column in select. Some DBMS also allows this shortcut for group by btw

Answer (score 1):

```
select (select fname||lname from "Employee" ) as fullname, avg(sal) from "Employee" GROUP by sal;
ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

This subquery returns two many records for a single column in whole query.

`(select fname||lname from "Employee" )`

```
SELECT * from "Employee";
 eid | fname  |  lname  | sal | loc 
-----+--------+---------+-----+-----
   1 | jake   | lee     | 200 | NY
   2 | stan   | spencer | 320 | NY
   3 | justin | jr      | 520 | CA
   1 | jake   | lee     | 200 | TX
(4 rows)
```

First, the GROUP BY clause divides rows of the table into groups, the AVG function is then applied for each group.

- AVG() function ignore NULL values when it calculates the average.

For example, to calculate the average amount paid by each customer,

```
SELECT
    fname || ' ' || lname AS "FullName",
    AVG(sal)
FROM "Employee"
GROUP BY fname,lname;
```

```
 FullName  |         avg          
-----------+----------------------
 lake e    | 320.0000000000000000
 justin jr | 520.0000000000000000
 jake lee  | 220.0000000000000000
(3 rows)
```

Comment: great explanation. Thank Rohit.

Comment: what if i want to use fname+lname, age,city from the table and group it by the sal. For sure group by will not let it happen.

Comment: @nancy_olson  if you have another question then post a new question but do not ask new question in comments

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer a more precise usage of the group by clause. The eid is characterizes an employee uniquely, not the fname-lname-pair. so the group by should be done by the eid. You have to add fname and lname to the group by clause because you want them in the select clause.

```
create table  empl (
    eid  number, 
    fname  varchar2(30),  
    lname  varchar2(30), 
    sal number, 
    loc varchar2(30));

insert into empl (eid , fname  ,  lname  , sal , loc ) 
    values(  1 ,'jake'    , 'lee'     , 200 , 'NY');
insert into empl (eid , fname  ,  lname  , sal , loc ) 
    values(   2 , 'stan'   , 'spencer' , 320 , 'NY');
insert into empl (eid , fname  ,  lname  , sal , loc ) 
    values(   3 , 'justin' , 'jr'      , 520 , 'CA');
insert into empl (eid , fname  ,  lname  , sal , loc ) 
    values(  1 , 'jake'   , 'lee'     , 200 , 'TX');

 SELECT
    fname || ' ' || lname AS FullName,
    AVG(sal)
FROM empl
GROUP BY eid,fname,lname
order by fname,lname,eid;
```

your data is not normalized and if there is a typo in a column your ouput is nonsense. So if your fourth insert statement is

```
insert into empl (eid , fname  ,  lname  , sal , loc ) 
    values(  1 , 'jack'   , 'lee'     , 200 , 'TX');
```

you get a completely different output

So maybe the following query may be a better variant:

```
 SELECT
    max(fname) || ' ' || max(lname) AS FullName,
    AVG(sal)
FROM empl
GROUP BY eid
order by max(fname),max(lname),eid;
```